# anchor tag in django template not working

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, anchor

In my django project, inside one of my templates, no anchor tag is working.
here is my code of template:
[layer_details.html](https://www.codepile.net/pile/4kzlGLNy)

When I click on any anchor, the url is showing in the browser but not redirecting to that link.

One of these is :

```
<a class="btn btn-link" href="{% url "layer_metadata" resource.service_typename %}">{% trans "Edit Layer Metadata" %}</a>
```

Comment: add code which is not working

Comment: hey @c.grey any anchor tag in this template is not working

Comment: post error traceback and urls.py code

Comment: Do you really expect us to read some 2000 lines of template code ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to access an anchor on another page the pattern looks more like

```
<a class="btn btn-link" href="{% url "url-name" arg1 %}#anchor">{% trans "Edit Layer Metadata" %}</a>
```